# Get full classname based on partial classname

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a full class name which contains a string 'CDW' in its name. For ex  I want to get for that elements with ID=1 the full classname of only CDW102.$(#1.hasClass['CDW']), get full classname which is CDW102 and I don't want the other class names for this element.
What I have tried so far is to find out if it has that class name or not using

```
$.fn.hasPartialClass = function (partial) {
    return new RegExp(partial).test(this.prop('class'));
};

var yes=$(this).hasPartialClass("CDW")

<td id="102" class="one two three CDW102">
```

How to get the fullclass name CDW102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get the fullclass name CDW102

You could split the classes up by their natural separator (a space), loop over them, and return the whole class if it's found.  If none are found, you can just let it return `false`.

```js
$.fn.hasPartialClass = function (partial) {
  var classes = this.prop('class').split(' ');
  for(var i = 0, len = classes.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(new RegExp(partial).test(classes[i])) {
      return classes[i];
    }
  }
  return false;
};

var yes=$('#102').hasPartialClass("CDW");

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(yes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="102" class="one two three CDW102"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can test your regex then conditionally return what you want like this:

```js
$.fn.hasPartialClass = function (partial) {
    if(new RegExp(partial).test(this.prop('class'))) {
      return this.prop('class');
    }
    return false;
};
```